# Ionic android build error after migrating to androidx

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-android

I am working on an ionic 3 project.i had to migrate to androidx due to a sudden build issue. I created the android platform with cordova-android@8.0.0 version and i did the needful but now i'm getting some other errors while building the android platform

I created the android platform with cordova-android version 8.0.0.

Added below lines to gradle.properties file

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Updated the plugins to the latest

this is my project.properties file

```
target=android-28
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-appsflyer-sdk/userapp-cordovaAF.gradle
cordova.system.library.1=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.40.0
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-firebase/userapp-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0
cordova.system.library.11=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0
cordova.system.library.12=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:18.0.0
cordova.system.library.13=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:18.0.0
cordova.gradle.include.4=cordova-plugin-googlemaps/userapp-tbxml-android.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.5=cordova-plugin-googlemaps/userapp-apikey.gradle
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.9=com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.+
cordova.system.library.10=com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.6.0
cordova.system.library.11=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+
cordova.system.library.14=com.android.support:support-v4:28.+
cordova.system.library.15=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:support-v4:28.+
cordova.system.library.4=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+
```

When i build the project now im getting below mentioned errors

```
error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
                             ^
 cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.os.EnvironmentCompat;

error: cannot find symbol
          public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult result) {
                                          ^
```

Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks

Comment: `project.properties` still references `com.android.support`. does that make sense?

Comment: When i changed it to this
`
cordova.system.library.9=androidx:support-core-utils:27.+
cordova.system.library.14=androidx:support-v4:28.+
cordova.system.library.15=androidx:appcompat-v7:28.+
`

im getting below error

`
Could not find any matches for androidx:support-v4:28.+ as no versions of androidx:support-v4 are available.
 Could not find any matches for androidx:appcompat-v7:28.+ as no versions of androidx:appcompat-v7 are available.
`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The errors are arising because your Android project contains Java source code (presumably in the form of Cordova plugins) which references the Android Support Library but you have enabled AndroidX in your project.

AndroidX and the Android Support Library cannot live side-by-side in the same Android project - doing so will lead to build failures such as this.

From your `project.properties` it can been seen that the Support Library is being pulled in as a Gradle dependency (e.g. `cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:support-v4:28.+`).

[AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) (Jetpack) is the successor to the [Android Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index). 

Note that AndroidX is now used by the [latest versions of Play Services & Firebase libraries](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019).

The Support library is used by many existing plugins such as [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase).

To resolve this issue, add the following two plugins your Cordova project:

- [cordova-plugin-androidx](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx) to enable AndroidX in the Android project.
- [cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter) to dynamically patch the source code of any plugins using the Support Library to use the AndroidX equivalents and to patch the Gradle config to replace Android Support Library references with AndroidX equivalents.

For a working example of this in a test project, see [my comment on this Github issue](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1081#issuecomment-503135862).

**Note:** if you are using [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) and encountering errors, you can instead use [my fork of that plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase) which is published as `cordova-plugin-firebasex` and is fixed to resolve issues caused by the new Firebase SDK. Here's the safest way to migrate:

```
rm -Rf platforms/android
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase
rm -Rf plugins/ node_modules/
npm install
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex
cordova platform add android
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I followed the steps you have mentioned and those errors i mentioned above are gone. But i'm getting the error

`cannot find symbol
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;`

Comment: I removed the firebase plugins and now it builds fine.. but i need the firebase plugin as well. But it gives me the error `annot find symbol import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;` What could be the reason?

Comment: `cordova-plugin-firebase` is out-of-date with respect to the latest changes in the Firebase SDK (that class has been removed). You can install directly from [my fork](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase) which has fixed that issue.

Comment: I'm trying to install your fork by adding it to the config.xml like this `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase.git" />` but its stuck in this `Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-firebase" in config.xml. Adding it to the project`

Comment: Also i tried adding the plugin like this `ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase.git`

But it gives me this error
`Installing "cordova-plugin-firebase" for android
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase': Error: Expected plugin to have ID "cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support" but got "cordova-plugin-cocoapod-supportx".
`

Comment: Thanks Dave, since 2 days i was blocked and with your cordova plugins, now it s working, thanks a lot

Comment: OMG ... THANK YOU SO MUCH! I have been trying to fix this for 2 days now and this morning I finally found this post and it's working again. THANK YOU!!

Comment: @DaveAlden Hi Dave, after i upgrade to cordova 9, when i try to install your plugin i get the fillowing error. using "requirecordovamodule" to load non-cordova module "fs" is not supported. instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it. but if i downgrade the cordova version i cannot add your plugin

Comment: Amazing!  God bless you and yours a thousand times my good man!
NOTE: adding these plugins may bump your `minSdkVersion` to 28; I had to bump it down to 22 to get my (v1 Ionic) Android app opening properly (it built fine, but trying to install the app to my device yielded an "There was a problem parsing the package." error.  I.e. I updated the given line in `config.xml` to this:
`<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />`