# error "requirecordovamodule" to load non-cordova module "fs" is not supported

Tags: cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins, cordova-android, cordova9

I was trying to install the [firebasex cordova plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56665580/3721080) and it requires 9>=cordova.  So I updated to cordova 9 and when trying to add the cordova plugins im getting the below error:

```
using "requirecordovamodule" to load non-cordova module "fs" is not supported. 
instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Basically because of cordova 9 remove support of browserify. So any fs or requred etc... will not support cause use by nodejs. 

If you want temporary solve it. You could downgrade it to cordova 8. Otherwise need to required source provider to do the changes.

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/03/22/cordova-cli-release-9.0.0.html

Answer (score 4):

You are maybe using old plugins...

Search for **'requirecordovamodule'** in all your code.
You might find lines like

`var fs = context.requirecordovamodule('fs');`

If it is in a plugin, try to update the plugin.

If no updates are available, you can try to replace the line by

`var fs = require('fs');`

Comment: Not working, even after searching code, nothing found like this.

Comment: A  little clarification..."All your code" includes plugins folder and node_modules folder